# I am using “@media print” for printing my html page. Here I am getting problum with background color is not visible of modelbox

Tags: html, css, printing

I am using “@media print” for printing my html page. Here I am getting problum with background color is not visible of modelbox, when I am trying to print my html page.

FF, Chrome is working fine but IE7 and IE8 it go off. Here is the link : http://jsfiddle.net/9BmXv/

attached screenshot is print preview of html.

[image: Having problum with background]

Comment: Did you try changing the background color to white (`#fff`)?

Comment: ya i tryed but wont working.. only border is working..

Answer (score 1):

Browsers usually have a user preference along the lines of "Print backgrounds" which is turned off by default (to avoid burning through vast amounts of ink). This cannot be overridden by page authors.

Consequently, print designs should almost always aim for a plain white background.

With a design like that, since the main content is covered up, you probably should `display: none` the main content so you are just printing the area you care about.

Comment: If you want to show main content, why are you covering it up with the model box?

Comment: i want both. Is there any chance to show content and model box?

Comment: Change the styles in the print media stylesheet so that the model box isn't positioned on top of the other content.

Comment: You have to put it somewhere! If you don't want to move the header and content, and you don't want to overlap the content, then put it after the content!

Comment: @Quentin let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2987/discussion-between-omm-and-quentin)

Answer (score 0):

It's a setting in IE.  I don't  think there's a great deal you can do about it other than design your page to work well when printed with white / transparent backgrounds

[image]

Comment: Normally people don't know about **Browser printing setting** to set background colors and image..